# Express $\cos \left ( 5x \right )$ via powers of $\sin \left ( x \right )$ and $\cos \left ( x \right )$?

Tags: trigonometry

Using De Moivres formula and Newtons binomial theorem. Also, express $\cos ^{5}\left ( x \right )$ via trigonometric functions of multiple angles. 
What I've managed to do so far:
$\left(\cos\left(x\right)+i\sin\left(x\right)\right)^{5}=\cos\left(5x\right)+i\sin\left(5x\right)$

and also, using the binomial factors:

$\left(\cos\left(x\right)+i\sin\left(x\right)\right)^{5}=\sum\dbinom5k\cos^{5-k}\left(x\right)i\sin^{k}\left(x\right)$

from there I got

$\cos\left(5x\right)=\cos^{5}\left(x\right)-10\cdot\cos^{3}\left(x\right)\cdot\sin^{2}\left(x\right)+5\cdot\cos\left(x\right)\cdot\sin^{4}\left(x\right)$

So, any more help on the second part? More hints?

Comment: Do you know how to expand $(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))^5$? If so, you can just equate real and imaginary parts of your equation to get the answer.

Comment: Smaller steps first. Do you know the binomial theorem? One of the things that it tells you, is that: $(a+b)^5=a^5+5a^4b+10a^3b^2+10a^2b^3+5ab^4+1$. EDIT: Never mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second part (express $\cos^5(x)$ without powers):

Let me use the notation $\newcommand{cis}{\operatorname{cis}}\cis(x)$ to mean $\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$. Note that $\cis(-x)=\cos(x)-i\sin(x)$. (Do you see why?)

Also note that $\cos(x)=\dfrac{\cis(x)+\cis(-x)}2$. (Do you see why?)

Finally, note that $\cis^n(x)=\cis(nx)$ (this is De Moivre's theorem). Also, $\cis(nx)\cis(mx)=\cis^n(x)\cis^m(x)=\cis^{n+m}(x)=\cis\big((n+m)x\big)$.

Raising this to the fifth power:
\begin{align}
\cos^5(x)&=\left(\frac{\cis(x)+\cis(-x)}2\right)^5\\
&=\frac{\cis(5x)+5\cis(3x)+10\cis(x)+10\cis(-x)+5\cis(-3x)+\cis(-5x)}{32}
\end{align}
Remembering that $\cis(x)+\cis(-x)=2\cos(x)$:
$$\boxed{\cos^5(x)=\frac1{16}\cos(5x)+\frac5{16}\cos(3x)+\frac58\cos(x)}$$

Comment: You may or may not have learned this already: $\operatorname{cis}(x)=e^{ix}$.

Comment: Well, sir, to answer your questions, yes I do see why. The sine is an odd function, and cosine is an even function. Your answer will be of great value for my rehearsals. Thanks.

Comment: @Shemafied Great! Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$\cos(5x) = \cos(2x + 3x) = \cos(2x) \cos(3x) - \sin(2x) \sin(3x)$$
Now make use of the following identities to obtain the answer:
\begin{align}
\cos(2x) & = 2\cos^2(x)-1\\
\cos(3x) & = 4\cos^3(x) - 3\cos(x)\\
\sin(2x) & = 2\sin(x) \cos(x)\\
\sin(3x) & = 3\sin(x) - 4\sin^3(x)
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

You've already know that: $$(\cos x + i \sin x)^5 = \cos(5x)+i\sin(5x).$$ But $(\cos x + i \sin x)^5 $ is equal to: $$\cos^5x + 5i\cos^4x \sin x + 10i^2 \cos^3 x \sin ^2x + 10i^3\cos^2x\sin^3x + 5i^4\cos x \sin^4x + i^5\sin^5x .$$
Don't be afraid to simplify this.